# How to convert JSON schema to Spark schema?

Tags: json, apache-spark, schema

I have a [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/) which I want to convert to Spark schema.
I thought [this library](https://github.com/zalando-incubator/spark-json-schema) from Zalando could help, but it seems to be no longer maintained and it does not work.

What else can I do? If you ask me, I thought this would be a fairly common use case so surprised Spark does not support it.